# Consuming speed slow down when set spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition in spark streaming application

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm a new comer at Stack Overflow. And I'm looking for some help for the problem I met.Thanks in advance.

I'm developing a spark-streaming application recently.These basic info about it:

1. spark version : 1.6.1
2. spark streaming source :  kafka
3. obtain data method ： Direct
4. duration: 10s
5. kafka version : 2.10_0.8.2.1
6. kafka topic partitions: 10

Because the kafka cluster may be already existed and may contains massive data in it.So I add configurations into spark conf as below:

1. spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled          true
2. spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition     6000

With the configurations I succeed limit the consuming speed when the spark driver first start up.The max event size is 6000 * 10 * 10 = 600000.

Then I met my problem.See the picture.

I have no enough reputations to upload pictures so I will describe it.

**batch time**                           **input size**

2017/04/19 18:08:20           100 events

2017/04/19 18:08:10           100 events

2017/04/19 18:08:00           60000 events

...

2017/04/19 18:07:20           60000 events

2017/04/19 18:07:10           60000 events

The consuming speed slow down suddenly from 600000 to 100.I tried several times,the results are same.At the beginning of restart,the consuming speed is 600000,after almost 10 batches,the speed suddenly down to 100.

And I try to decrease the maxRatePerPartition number,but it still slow down gradully like from 30000 to 2650 and at last 100.And there are no warning or error logs come out.I'm confused.

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.Thanks.

Comment: sorry if the question is stupid, but do you have more than 100 new msg/sec in your kafka cluster ? this looks like your application is processing the whole kafka buffer, then handles the latest messages, so at the same rate as they are inserted.

Comment: I'm sure there are still massive data in my kafka cluster.The number may be billions, and I'm sure the data is not overdue.This confuse me.

Comment: I think I've found the reason already.This result relate to Spark dynamic rate control mechanism

Comment: The config name is spark.streaming.backpressure.pid.minRate.

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful for me. i was wondering its an issue only for me !!!! spark.streaming.backpressure.pid.minRate what value you set as ?